# Redefined abstract environment aligned incorrectly

Tags: vertical-alignment, page-numbering, abstract

In order to prevent the abstract environment from resetting the page numbering, I have redefined the environment as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}    

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
  \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
      {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
  \fi}
  {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract...
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

This does the job but the abstract is no longer centred vertically. I'm not familiar with redefining environments - can anyone tell me how I can adjust the code above so that my abstract stays in the middle of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this definition for your abstract:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \clearpage\small
    \null\vfil
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    }
{\endquotation\vfil\null\clearpage}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
    \clearpage\small
    \null\vfil
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{0pt}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    }
{\endquotation\vfil\null\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract...
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Unhelpful content 1}
\section{Unhelpful content 2}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the command `\vfil`. Out of interest, the original definition of the abstract environment uses \@beginparpenalty, is this what causes the page number to reset?

Comment: @TomOffer No, `\endtitlepage` resets it.

Comment: `\vspace*{\fill}` is better, IMO. In any case, the `\null` at the end does nothing and you should instead add `\clearpage`. Also `\par` is redundant: `\endquotation` issues one.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, it makes a difference. `\vspace*{\fill}` is more infinite than `\vfil`, so it will kill the flexible glue around `center` and `quotation` even if it had first order infinite components. Moreover, if what comes after `\end{abstract}` doesn't start a new page, you'd be in trouble without `\clearpage`, wouldn't you? Besides, promoting `\null` is wrong, because it's quite a dangerous command. I'd prefer `\clearpage\vspace*{\fill}` to start, for the same reason why `\clearpage is needed at the end.

Comment: @egreg I agree only about `\par` and `\clearpage`

Comment: @TomOffer I've slightly improved the definition. Please use the updated one.

Comment: @egreg And I'm not promoting `\null`. It is in the definition of `abstract` in `report.cls`...

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, I had been reading the comments and updated the definition myself :) The `\vspace*{\fill}` command seems to mess with the vertical alignment so I have stuck with `\vfil`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd not vertically center the abstract: it appears to hang from nothing.

However, here's a possible definition that leaves you a different choice: the optional argument to `\begin{abstract}` is a fraction for stating the relative distance from the top of the page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\renewenvironment{abstract}[1][1]
 {\clearpage
  \vspace*{\stretch{#1}}
  \begin{center}
  \bfseries\abstractname
  \end{center}
  \quotation}
 {\endquotation\vfill\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract...
\end{abstract}

\begin{abstract}[.3]
This is the abstract...
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, I'd use the `book` class and `\chapter{\abstractname}` in `\frontmatter`.

Comment: Using `\vfil` as in the answer above seems to align the abstract roughly vertically central, like the original environment does. It works for me!